# JsRender if-else renders nothing

Tags: javascript, templates, jsrender

I have a simple model:

```
var model =  [{
    content: "",
    type: "photo",
    src: "xxx"
}, {
    content: "",
    type: "quote",
    text: "blah"
}];
```

and a simple template:

```
{{if type eq='photo'}}
    <img src="{{:src}}" />
    <div class="photo-caption">
        {{:caption}}
    </div>
{{else type eq='quote'}}
    <div class="quote-text">
        {{:text}}
    </div>
{{/if}}
```

The problem is that the template renders nothing at all when the `type` is "quote".  If I change it slightly to two `if`s instead of an `if-else`, it renders the quote, but also renders the `div class="photo-caption">`.  I need it to only render one or the other.  I have a feeling it's a simple matter of syntax, but can't seem to find sufficient docs on how this is done correctly on the JsRender site.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4QzZX/).  The two templates *should* behave exactly alike.  Instead one renders both, the other renders only the image.

Comment: If you make a jsFiddle, you'll have a much better chance of being helped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it:

```
{{if type == 'quote' }}
    <div>
        {{: text }}
    </div>     
{{else type == 'photo'}}   
    <div> 
        {{: src }} 
     </div>   
{{/if}}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4QzZX/2/

Comment: The docs here: http://www.jsviews.com/#iftag say "Conditional inclusion: — Render the block content of the {{if}} tag (or the referenced external template) only if the data-path or expression evaluates to true ('or truthy')". 
See the example at the bottom: {{if members && members.length}}...{{else standby && standby.length}}...{{else}}...{{/if}}. You can basically use any javascript expression... So {{if a<3 && b===c || defaultValue}}... would be fine. If you need complex code use helpers: {{if ~someCalculatedValue(someField) > someOtherFieldValue}}... is also fine...

Comment: FYI:  @BorisMoore the author of JSRender.  So it is likely he knows what he is talking about.  Thank you Boris!

Answer (score -2):

When you tried the version with two if statements, did you remember to add a `{{/if}}` in addition to changing the `{{else}}` into an `{{if}}`?

```
{{if type eq='photo'}}
    <img src="{{:src}}" />
    <div class="photo-caption">
        {{:caption}}
    </div>
{{/if}}
{{if type eq='quote'}}
    <div class="quote-text">
        {{:text}}
    </div>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: @wtfsven: well, thats pretty weird then. Maybe you should try creating a small executable JSFiddle reproducing your problem.